# Jquery anchor link Event

Tags: jquery

i have a html like this

```
<a href="link.php" onClick="return false;">Click me</a>

$('a').click(function() {
var linked = "#"+$(this) .attr(href);
window.location=linked;
})
```

why this not working?

Comment: i want like this url : #index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a').click( function( event ) {
    location.href = '#' + $(this).attr( 'href' );
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation(); // sometimes useful
    return false; // sometimes useful
} );
```

you should supress the triggered event

Comment: You do not need to both `preventDefault()` _and_ `return false`. One or the other is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
var linked = "#"+$(this) .attr(href);
```

by

```
var linked = "#"+$(this).attr("href");
```

**EDIT**

Try with this

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var linked = "#"+$(this).prop("href");
    window.location.hash = linked;
});​
```

Comment: Because what you're trying to change is the hash of the url (url#hash)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you don't need JavaScript at all. Just change the `href`:

```
<a href="#link.php">Click me</a>
```

Comment: i know but not basic your says;
i have give normal link but must work anchor link

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the `onClick="return false;"` part first and see what happens

Comment: with return false; the browser not going this href  but google can take index